# How to prevent Ajax/javascript result caching in browsers?

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching

How to prevent browsers from caching Ajax results?  I have and event triggered Ajax script the displays results only when the browsers data has been cleared.

*Tested in IE6 and Firefox 3.0.10*

Comment: actually, this is a pretty well documented problem. I'm sure you can find a very comprehensive answer if you google for it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a random query string to the URL you are sending.

E.g. if the Ajax request is sent to "http://www.xyz.com/a"
then add a random string at the end: "http://www.xyz.com/a?q=39058459ieutm39"

Comment: ...and you can generate the random string in javascript for example like this: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)

Comment: This solution has a serious drawback: it fills the cache if you retrieve many files. In my case, I want to preserve the cache for offline use, so I don't want to fill it with old versions of the request.

Answer (score 15):

The random URL works, but it's kind of a hack.  HTTP has solutions built in that should work.  Try using the solution [indicated here](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg33/).  Basically, set the headers:

```
"Pragma":            "no-cache",
"Cache-Control":     "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
"Expires":           0,
"Last-Modified":     new Date(0), // January 1, 1970
"If-Modified-Since": new Date(0)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

(Though it seems strange that the headers are set on the client rather than in the response from the server!)

Comment: I get an error trying to implement your solution: `request header field pragma is not allowed by "access-control-allow-headers"`. Any idea how to avoid this? Look:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048184/xmlhttprequest-with-no-cache-request-header-is-not-allowed

Comment: A call I was making would fail when passing a random number through the query string.  I didn't build the service but it seemed as though it was trying to interpret every parameter.  This was the perfect solution, thanks!

Comment: We had an issue with the `new Date(0)` where the request failed because the date is in invalid format for a Russian user. So better write some date yourself like: `"Wed, 21 Oct 1970 07:28:00 GMT"` instead of using `new Date(0)`

Answer (score 9):

I've used the jQuery {cache: false} method and it worked like a charm.

The complete code example is like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
```

Comment: ajaxSetup works only for ajax calls. For other JS calls, you may need to add the querystring random string hack.

Comment: I added that before the new XMLHttpRequest(); and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

There are two techniques for this that I'm aware of.

- Add some sort of query string to the AJAX request URL so that it's always unique. A millisecond timestamp (perhaps combined with a random value) is good for this
- Set HTTP cache control headers on the AJAX response so that the browser doesn't cache it

Answer (score 4):

using jQuery you can set global ajax setting: { cache: false }. See it in [jquery ajax docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options)