# ajax - how to clear previous ajax result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax call, which works for the most part, but it does seem to memorize the previous result. Edit: this likely is due to binding a behavior to a divid.

The structure of my routine is like this:

1. call ajax to search if the input is good or not, get response back from php.  Result can be either Yes or No.
2. If result is Yes, change the color of a holder div as a visual cue, allow user to doubleclick on the div to run another function.  If not, don't allow doubleclick div and don't run another function.

Easy right? Except that when the first ajax call yields a 'Yes' result, and then the user perform a second ajax call and it yields a 'No' result, the user can dblclick on 'No' result and perform the action intended for a 'Yes' result.

I try to unbind the dblclick, but it does not seem to work, and would still allow the no result to be clicked on.  This is my jquery code, my regular javascript code has the same bad behavior.

Edit: this appears to be a binding problem.  But I can seem to unbind and destroy/delete the previously bound behavior.  Further testing by repeating the routine seem to indicate that javascript does save these bound objects in memory because the alert would echo back as many "saved" bound objects when I repeated the error routine many times.

My partial code is below, any insight is appreciated.

TIA

Edit: the solution is to unbind the doubleclick, I should had type dblclick instead of doubleclick

```
function search(input,divid) {

var queryString = "name=" + input+"&divid="+divid;
var url = "../l.php";

      $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: url,
      data: queryString,
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'text',
      timeout: 10000, 

      error: function(xhr, status, error) { alert('Search Error: '+ xhr.status+ ' - '+ error); },

      success: function(response) { 

      var result = response;
      var err = /:/;
      var divid = "#"+divid;


      if (result == "Yes" ) 
      { 
        $(tldid).attr({'class':'tg1', 'title':'Doubleclick to save'});

        var testword = 'xyz';
        $(divid).dblclick(function() {
            alert (testword);

                    $(divid).unbind('doubleclick');
                   });

       else {
         //alert (testword +" should not have been passed here, but it does");
                 $(divid).attr({'class':'tg2'});
        }


      }//success
    });

}//end
```

Comment: Yes, Browser gets you results from cache in the subsequent calls when you URL is same. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948828/how-to-prevent-ajax-javascript-result-caching-in-browsers   to handle it via adding timestamp or another query param to URL

Comment: @sudmong: He has already set `cache: false`. Setting cache to false appends a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL

Comment: @sudmong, I think you miss understand my problem, it is not a browser cache problem, I am aware of that problem, I set the cache to false.  As I typed the question, it appears that it is the binding problem.

Comment: I went by your first statement which says "but it does seem to memorize/cache the previous result." ???

Comment: @sudmong, sorry for the confusing language, I don't know what the error is, so I can't accurately name it.

Comment: `var divid = "#"+divid;` remove the `var`; the variable is already defined.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, thanks, I changed the var names before I posted, and I am that was not the cause.  It was due to the binding, I needed to unbind, see my reply to Ben.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should change `$(divid).unbind('doubleclick');` to `$(divid).unbind('dblclick');`.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I totally overlooked that.  I got the "doubleclick" from this guide http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/events/the-unbind-method/  which could be a typo.  I am glad I came across this problem, it could partially explain why my script cause the browser to be sluggish.