# AJAX not working consistently

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've spent a while trying to figure this one out. I'm sure someone with the right experience will be able to see the issue, but I just can't understand why it's not working consistently.

Basically, all this does is make two calls. It gets a number when the page loads. Then when the user submits a form, it makes a 2nd call, which tells my PHP file to simply add 1 to the current total number of submissions.

It works most of the time, and it even seems to work for me in IE7 and IE8 (sort of - it seems to cache the number somehow, so you can only tell it's been updated from a different browser).

EDIT: I've only tested IE7 and IE8 using IE9's developer tools, haven't tried on an actual install of those myself.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;
      var url = "counter.php?myaction=getcount";
      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      updateCounter(request.responseText);
    }
  };
  request.send(null);

});

    function doNothing() {};

    function addCount() {

  var request2 = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;
      var url2 = "counter.php?myaction=addcount";
      request2.open('GET', url2, true);
      request2.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request2.readyState == 4) {
      request2.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      updateCounter(request2.responseText);
              $('#stcPetitionForm').submit();
    }
  };
  request2.send(null);     

    }

    function updateCounter(numSubmissions) {
            $("#myCounter").html("<p>" + numSubmissions + "</p>");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET requests are cached. Are you setting no cache headers on the serverside?

Comment: For some reason my comments aren't showing up...

EDIT: Okay well that one did. Here's what I tried to say:

I've fixed the caching issue. Is that likely to affect the 2nd call? The PHP simply looks at the value of 'myaction' that is sent over, and if it's 'addcount', it looks at the current value of the form submissions and increases it by 1. Would caching have prevented this from occurring after the 1st time someone fills out the form, if they wanted to fill it out again?

Comment: If you are updating state on the server, you should be doing a POST not a GET.

Comment: It also receives that number back to update it on the current page (although I suppose I could have done that with JS)

Comment: @user1020189: if you saw my answer, you'd see an example that make sense.  `new Date()` gets a refresh of the date/time from the system.  `.getTime()` returns the time in milliseconds (thus, the number always increases), which makes it perfect for passing as a value.  It might be useful to have the time for something you're doing anyhow, so it's not just a random value, its actually useful

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly well documented issue. [How to prevent Ajax/javascript result caching in browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948828/how-to-prevent-ajax-javascript-result-caching-in-browsers) provides some good solutions you could try.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because GET requests are cached.

Example of how to avoid caching:

- ```
  var d    = new Date();
  var url2 = "counter.php?myaction=addcount&time=' + d.getTime();
  // you'd apply to all your url's not just url2
  ```

To Demonstrate the getTime:

- ```
  function postTime(){
     var d = new Date();
     console.log(d.getTime());
  }

  setInterval(postTime,1000);
  ```