# JavaScript:: How to prevent caching in XMLHttpRequest from JS?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent Ajax/javascript result caching in browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948828/how-to-prevent-ajax-javascript-result-caching-in-browsers)

I want to load JS-script dynamically. Every time browser load old version of file?

How to prevent load new version of file without server-code changes?

Comment: post some codes what you've tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way would be to send the request by sending a random number as parameter each time so that browser does not cache the request!

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somejsfile.js?r=random_number"></script>
```

a random number can be generated each time by a script which loads before this!

I'm not sure if this is the right way, but it does the job fine!

Answer (score 7):

For the random number part as suggested by sandeepraju:

```
var url = "jsfile.js?" + new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: as long as the calls are at least 1 ms apart I think this the best approach