# Calling WebAPI from JavaScript second time

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have very simple OWIN WebApp that hosts one simple controller in console application. Then I have ASP.NET MVC Application and from view I am calling that Web API from JavaScript like this:

```
function callRest() {
    var url = "http://localhost:9151/api/values";

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("GET", url, false);
    request.send();

    if (request.status == 200)
        alert("The request succeeded!\n\nThe response representation was:\n\n" + request.responseText)
    else
        alert("The request did not succeed!\n\nThe response status was: " + request.status + " " + client.statusText + ".");

}
```

This works. Call really make a call into WebAPI controller and it returns a value. However if I call callRest() function again within the same session (second time click on button), it does not really call WebAPI, but instead immediately returns cached values. How can I make that whenever I call WebAPI it is actually called and not returned from cache?

Answer (score 0):

try using getTime() :

```
var url = "http://localhost:9151/api/values?"+new Date().getTime();
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

This is by intent to save round-trip time. If you want a new request, the request parameters need to be different otherwise it will cache.

To accomplish that, you could follow the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181859/javascript-how-to-prevent-caching-in-xmlhttprequest-from-js).

By simply adding a random number to the request it forces the browser to NOT cache.