# Is there nowadays a crossbrowser and standard compliant way to prevent caching when using an XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, xmlhttprequest, standards, cache-control

Is there nowadays a crossbrowser and standard compliant way to prevent caching when using an XMLHttpRequest?

So far even MDN suggests a workaround. ([MDN XMLHttpRequest#Bypassing_the_cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Bypassing_the_cache))

(like [Add a random query string to the URL you are sending.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/948839/4550791))

Edit: The question is about telling the browser not to use it's clientside cache, independently from what the server send as flags or fields.

Comment: Proper way is for the server to tell not to cache anything. In that case there is no need for workarounds, if the browsers do what they're told.

Comment: Caching control is really the responsibility of the *server*, since it's supposed to know the nature of the resources it's serving.

Comment: No, there is no such way.

Answer (score 0):

You can control how you cache data with `Cache-Control` headers

Something like this - `cache-control: private, max-age=0, no-cache`

Read more here - http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en

Comment: This is a server side solution, but OP has revised the question to want only client side solutions.