# Random API calls always give same result

Tags: javascript, rest, api, google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome extension, I am periodically making API calls to a URL to get random information.

```
function get_quote_api(){
              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        //handle the xhr response here
        console.log(xhr.responseText)
      }
    }
    xhr.send();

}

window.setInterval(function(){
  get_quote_api()
}, 5000);
```

When I test this API call in postman, on each call it gives random quotes. But, in the JavaScript program, each call always gets the same quotes. What its happening? What do I need to change?

Comment: Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948828/how-to-prevent-ajax-javascript-result-caching-in-browsers

Comment: So you are saying that this is cache issue@PaulAbbott

Comment: @akhilviswam, inspect the devtools network panel for normal page and the page of your extension (background page or whatever else) and you'll see the difference yourself.